# Stretching a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I'm using `tikzpicture` to do things, and I want to create a number line that is stretched. Kinda like the 3b1b group theory video.

[image: Example of something I want to achieve (From 3Blue1Brown)]

I know it's already pretty easy to do this, but I also want to get an automated macro like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\stretch}[2]{
    ???
}
```

I've already tried, but to no avail. (Prepare for dumb coding.)

```latex
\newcommand{\stretch}[2]{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \[\mathbf(#1\times #2)\]
        \draw[<->] (#1-2,0)--(#2+2,0);
        \draw[<->] (#1-2,-3)--(#2+2,-3);
        \foreach \x in {\number\numexpr-#1-1\relax,...,0,...\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}  
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0.2pt) -- (0pt,-0.2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \foreach \x in {\number\numexpr-#1*#2\relax,...,\number\numexpr-#2\relax,0,#2...\number\numexpr#1*#2\relax}  
        \draw[shift={(\x,-3)},color=black] (0pt,0.2pt) -- (0pt,-0.2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Do have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

Like this? ( I've used 2 times grater and you can change it to 3 or any in `\draw[shift={(\x*2,2)},color=black]`)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[<->] (-7,2)--(7,2);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,...,3}
\draw[shift={(\x*2,2)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};

\draw[->, thick,green] (0,3)--(0,2.2);

\draw[<->] (-7,0)--(7,0);
\foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** If you want a macro it should be something like this (but I don't recommend it because you should choose input carefully and the output is a but ugly):

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5] \draw[<->] (-3*#1-1,2)--(3*#1+1,2); \foreach \x in {-3,-2,...,3} \draw[shift={(\x*#1,2)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$}; \draw[->, thick,green] (0,3)--(0,2.2); \draw[<->] (-7,0)--(7,0); \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$}; \end{tikzpicture}}
```

and use it as `\mycommand{3}`.

Comment: Alright. So if I want to do a macro, can I do this:
\newcommand{\command}{1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[<->] (-7,2)--(7,2);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,...,3}
\draw[shift={(\x*#1,#1)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};

\draw[->, thick,green] (0,3)--(0,2.2);

\draw[<->] (-7,0)--(7,0);
\foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: When I used it for 4, I receive this result: https://imgur.com/Us5In09

Comment: it is your page size or size of figure problem. it is too large for `article` or `book` documentclass. I've added `[scale=.5]` in the `thikzpicture` option (for \mycommand). now it seems OK.

Comment: Why you changed the code unprofessionally? the number labels misplaced in your linked screenshot.

Comment: Note that this is not correct: `{(\x*4,4)}` the correct one is `{(\x*4,2)}` (shift horizontally)